# class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes\

Tags: java, bouncycastle

when I ran a method to sign for PDF automatically with a main method in the same java file,it can be succeeded.but when I ran the same method to sign for PDF automatically with JSP action from other java file,it gave me below error:

```
2017/05/04 17:50:43 : ERROR [com.esa2000.pdfsign.SealControl.signWithCert(SealControl.java:863)] java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:806)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:487)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:625)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3196)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1373)
```

all the files are in the same project.I checked other referances from website and said it is an issue about bouncycastle jar.The jar I used in my project is bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar. Can anyone give me some advices?Thank a lot!!

Comment: I'll bet it's a version issue with your Bouncy Castle JAR.  The message suggests that someone made a change that doesn't match the cert.  Find another JAR.

Comment: thank you for you suggestion and I tried but the issue persisted.I am trying other solutions.